# Get test list in MSTest via Command-Line

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

How can I get the test list in MSText.exe via command-line?

The help command tells me to get the test list with the test metadata, but the metadata needs a vsdmi file, which my project (Visual Studio 2013) didn't create anywhere. (I have already created an unit test in a test project).

I want a list of all the tests in my project; not to run them, just the list.